# Why webpack bundle is successfully built and run without multi-stage docker build?

Tags: docker, npm, webpack

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.4.0 as builder
COPY ./package.json /src/package.json
ENV PORT 3000
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
COPY ./lerna.json /src/lerna.json
COPY ./packages/package-api/package.json /src/packages/package-api/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-config/package.json /src/packages/package-config/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-sitemap/package.json /src/packages/package-sitemap/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-utils/package.json /src/packages/package-utils/package.json
RUN npm run clean
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src/packages/package-sitemap
RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.4.0
RUN echo "starting 2nd stage"
WORKDIR /src/packages/package-sitemap
COPY --from=builder /src/packages/package-sitemap/build/bundle.js .
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["node" , "bundle.js"]
```

running the bundle built from such Dockerfile results in following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'debug'`.

However if I remove the second stage and build the bundle in one stage there's no error and the bundle runs successfully, that is with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.4.0 as builder
COPY ./package.json /src/package.json
ENV PORT 3000
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
COPY ./lerna.json /src/lerna.json
COPY ./packages/package-api/package.json /src/packages/package-api/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-config/package.json /src/packages/package-config/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-sitemap/package.json /src/packages/package-sitemap/package.json
COPY ./packages/package-utils/package.json /src/packages/package-utils/package.json
RUN npm run clean
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src/packages/leaf-sitemap
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["node" , "build/bundle.js"]
```

I'm wondering what the difference can be? Is it because in the 2nd Dockerfile node_modules exist as well and webpack somehow sets paths to some modules in the bundle to the node_modules?

Comment: can you show the import section of bundle js? I do not thin bundle.js is frontend build artefact, it seems like nodejs file that serves distribution?

Comment: I see that there're some `require`s in the bundle code like: `B.ValidationError=E,t.exports=B},function(t,e){t.exports=require("url")},function(t,e){t.exports=require("safe-buffer")},` and there're webpack `require`s: `var callSiteToString=__webpack_require__(267).callSiteToString,eventListenerCount=__webpack_require__(267).event`. did you want to see something more specific?